# Laravel 5 redirecting to auth/login causes failure

Tags: php, laravel-5

Working with Laravel 5 I'm facing an issue to where it routes to auth/login by default.  When you login, it redirects to login causing an error.  When I'm able to actually use `http://localhost/login` it actually routes to home like it should.  Anything new that would be causing it behave like this?

HomeController shown below:

```
<?php namespace app\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function showLogin()
{
       // show the form
       return view('login');
}



public function doLogin()
{
// validate the info, create rules for the inputs
$rules = array(
    'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
    'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
);

// run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('login')
        ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
        ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
} else {

// create our user data for the authentication
$userdata = array(
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
);

// attempt to do the login
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

    // validation successful!
    // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
    // return Redirect::to('secure');
    // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
    echo 'SUCCESS!';

} else {        

    // validation not successful, send back to form 
    return Redirect::to('login');

}

}
}

public function doLogout()
{
    Auth::logout(); // log the user out of our application
    return Redirect::to('login'); // redirect the user to the login screen
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out to be that constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I removed that and changed the view to 'auth/login' and it works like a charm.